# Sticky Header with Slide down effect

Tags: jquery, css, sticky

I want when I scroll up my page header will go up also but after scroll position 150 it will slide down smoothly and fixed on top. I tried many ways but not really get proper results. Would guys see my code please?

something like this http://cssdeck.com/labs/sticky-header-with-slide-down-effect this script have some glitch.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $('.navarea').addClass('fixed-header');

        } else {
            $('.navarea').removeClass('fixed-header');
        }
    });
});
```

here is css

```
.navarea {

    z-index: 2;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fixed-header {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    text-shadow: none;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Live URL:
https://codepen.io/pagol/pen/XovvGJ

Comment: Yeah I tried your code too , It isn't working for some weird reason , I even tried to create a new one , Still its not working , I don't understand why

Comment: @thanveer Thanks for trying

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: @ThanveerShah i fixed something and also change view output panel side then i will work. but slide down animation not work yet

Comment: Targeting a class on scroll is bad. Performance killer. Cache your selectors, use a throttle for your scroll callback.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for suggestion. can you share with what is best way to do this. please

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *`"but after scroll position 150 it will slide down smoothly and fixed on top"`* - it could mean anything. Specially when in your code you use `100` as some reference value...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please check my reference url then you can understand easily. when you will scroll down. header/menu slidedown from top and sticky on top. that i want to do

Comment: Therefore it's also not clear the first *`"when I scroll up my page header will go up"`* up? where up?

Comment: So you want the exact same behavior like in the demo - but without glitches? Or something else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187015/discussion-between-pagol-and-roko-c-buljan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that

- creates a deep clone of the navigation element (other solutions were buggy after lots of testing)
- uses CSS3 `transition` for the cloned navigation
- uses a debounce callback mechanism to leverage functions triggered on scroll
- uses `position sticky` and `visibility` for the original element to improve the effect

```js
// https://github.com/micro-js/debounce/blob/master/lib/index.js
function debounce(fn, time) {
  var pending = null
  return function() {
    if (pending) clearTimeout(pending)
    pending = setTimeout(run, time)
    return function() {
      clearTimeout(pending)
      pending = null
    }
  }
  function run() {
    pending = null
    fn()
  }
}

function documentScrollTop() {
  const doc = document.documentElement;
  return (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
}

const el_nav1 = document.getElementById("nav");
const el_nav2 = el_nav1.cloneNode(true);
el_nav1.parentNode.insertBefore(el_nav2, el_nav1);
el_nav2.style.cssText = `position:fixed; transform:translateY(-100%);`;

function animateNavigation() {
  const canShow = documentScrollTop() >= 150;
  el_nav2.style.transform = `translateY(${canShow?0:-100}%)`;
  el_nav1.style.cssText = `position:${canShow?'sticky':'relative'}; visibility:${canShow?'hidden':'visible'};`
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', debounce(animateNavigation, 99));
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', animateNavigation);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ *{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;} html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}
p {height:300vh;border:4px dashed #000;} /* force scrollbars */

#nav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: gold;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">NAVIGATION HERE</nav>
<p></p>
```

Room for improvement

- Try to use only one element (the scroll back to top is hard here...)
- Use an additional condition inside the `animateNavigation` function that tests if an action was already performed (to prevent additional calls to `style` until `canShow` switches to a new boolean value)

Comment: thank you so much for help. you spend much time. thanks again